# How to implement this field in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form layout in ExtJS. In this layout there should be a field with a list of values (see the screenshot).

[image]

What kind of ExtJS component will help me implement this kind of field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `tagfield`. See the documentation [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html).

Comment: Thanks,  you helped me